# DNS server cannot resolve ipredator.se domain

Tags: networking, dns

Since yesterday I cannot connect to ipredator.se anymore. Seems to be a DNS problem:

```
$ nslookup ipredator.se
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find ipredator.se: SERVFAIL
```

But using a different nameserver works:

```
$ nslookup ipredator.se 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8                                                            
Address:        8.8.8.8#53                                                         

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ipredator.se
Address: 193.234.198.40
Name:   ipredator.se
Address: 193.234.198.41
```

All other domains I've tried work fine with the standard nameserver. Does anyone know what that means? Could it be that IPredator is blocked, either by my ISP or by the local router? (don't have admin access to it)

Comment: Are you running dnsmasq?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like your network has a internal DNS Server whitch is 127.0.1.1 .
I would think there could be a missconfiguration on that server. A local DNS Server dosent know by default any Internet ips or Hostnames. If the local DNS cant resolve a name he asks other DNS servers. The default DNS server configuration comes along with a list of DNS servers whitch he could ask to resolve names. Maybe the configuration was changed somehow?

Comment: It's not even network internal, it's in the original poster's computer. All 127/8 IPs are directed to localhost. So unless the user is running their own DNS server, the DNS settings are incorrect.

Comment: You are right, missed that point.